# Using PHP to call Virtualenv’ed Python Script

Tags: php, python, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04

Last night I spent 5.5 hours trying make PHP execute and receive the output of Virtualenv’ed Python script. Nothing worked; except for scripts that were not Virtualenv’ed.

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to make PHP call a virtualenv’d install of the Newspaper lib output text when I call it.

**What I have now:**

*PHP:* (updated)

```
<?php
$output = exec('newspaper2/bin/python3 /var/www/html/components/python/test.py 2>&1', $output2);
print_r(error_get_last());
echo $output2;
echo $output;
```

…this works when using a non-virtualenv script

*Python:* (updated)

```
from newspaper import Article
url = 'http://example.com/'
article = Article(url)
article.download()
article.html
article.parse()
article.authors
article.publish_date
string = article.text
print(string)
```

**What the issue is:**

I can run the script that PHP is running from the command line and it outputs just fine.

**What I have tried:**

With PHP, (I have tried all the “exec” calls for PHP) it cannot seem to open the virtual environment and returns nothing.

Before the script I have called “python3” and a few other things to no avail.

Yes, I have chmoded it to be executable…

I feel like this should be so simple.

I have tried suggestions on other posts and all over the web to no avail.

**Questions:**

- Did I set up the virtualenv wrong?
- At the top of the Python script, instead of the “#!/usr/bin/env python3” should I call something else?
- If so, where do I find it? Should I start from scratch and will that 
  help?

Thank you for your help;

PS: I am running Ubuntu16, PHP7 and I need to use Python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally figured it out and learned a lot in the process. The `newspaper` lib that I am using by default tries to write to the base of the users home directory. In this case, it was attempting to write to `www-data`, `/var/www`.

**To fix this:**

1. Go to the `settings.py` file in the `newspaper` library.
2. Edit the variable `DATA_DIRECTORY = '.newspaper_scraper'` and change it to `DATA_DIRECTORY = '.path/to/writable/directory'`
3. Save the file and you should be good to go.

I have no idea why it was not returning the errors that would have explained this sooner.

Hope this helps anyone else.

Thank you so much Sergey Vasilyev for your help. I appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 5):

In the virtualenv'ed scripts (i.e. installed via the setuptools' entry-points), you should not touch the shebang (`#!...` first line). It is populated by the virtualenv & setuptools & related tools.

If you specify your own shebang, then it is not virtualenv'ed script. In that case, call python directly:

```
exec('/path/to/venv/bin/python3 /var/www/html/components/python/testing.py');
```

Alternatively, you can put the absolute path to the virtualenv's python binary to the py-script, but this does not look a good idea.

Also, remember that virtualenvs are non-relocatable. So they should stay in the path where they were created.

Also note that `exec()` returns only the last line of the output. You probably want `shell_exec()` or `exec('...', $output)` to get the whole output.

Also, it is unclear what happens with your script, and what is being printed on stderr. Try this command to see what is the error:

```
exec('/path/to/script 2>&1', $output)
#OR:
exec('/path/to/venv/bin/python3 /path/to/script 2>&1', $output)
```

Comment: I see. Since I modified the shebang, do I need to recreate the virtualenv? I don't think I moved the virtualenv script, if so, do I delete it and start over? Thanks

Comment: Either restore the original shebang, or start over.

Comment: OK I was not sure how to "restore the original shebang" so I created a new virtualenv. I created a new script inside it, it did NOT create its own shebang. I ran it fine from the command line though... with `newspaper2/bin/python3 /var/www/html/components/python/test.py` . Nothing from PHP. It threw `sh: 1: newspaper2/bin/python3: not found` Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please add the full php & py scripts to the question? And the directory structure (venv, php&py scripts)

Comment: SPecifically, why is it `newspaper2/bin/python3`? Where is the leading part? Try with the absolute path.

Comment: Your last comment: I cant find the absolute path for some reason. Seems to work fine from shell.... Comment before: updated.

Comment: And nothing on stderr (in `$output2`)? That is strange. At least, I would expect an import error there. Can you replace this script's content with just a single `print('hello')`? No imports, nothing else. Will it work?

Comment: Oh that error? It changed to: "sh: 1: newspaper2/bin/python3: not found"

Comment: Ok. This means, there is no python3 executable at that path. You need to find where it lies (`which python3` with the actiated vitualenv will help; it should be `/path/to/your/venv/bin/python3`).

Comment: Found it and added it to PHP exec line. New error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/.newspaper_scraper'. Do I have to make it accessible for anything?

Comment: I tried creating another virtualenv in the server dir: /var/www/html/components/python/newspaper3/ but I still get the error: 'PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/.newspaper_scraper' I even 'chmoded -R 0777' that entire directory. I can't think what the issue is.

Comment: @regor2 I do not understand what exactly you do or did. Your paths are too different (again). Please, provide the exact reproducible description of your problem. Otherwise, it is difficult to guess what can be wrong.

Comment: This is kind of brute-force: I took a snapshot of my VM before all this and I am planning to roll it back to it. What is the _proper_ way to set this all up properly? Including location of envs, permissions, and so on? I've tried so many things!