# What can be the reasons of a FileNotFoundError if the file exists and is referenced rightly?

Tags: php, python, python-imaging-library

I am creating a website in which I execute a python file from php, with the check_call() function.

This python script, by the end of the algorithm, saves an image at a subdirectory of `/tmp` in my server (Ubuntu). However, I get this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/subdirectory/filename.png'

The image is saved with the PIL method `Image.save()`, which creates a new file if the file is not availabel (I have already tested it).

I have no doubt about the correctness of the path. I have checked and double-checked that I am using an absolute path, that the subdirectory is spelled right and that it exists.

If this could be a problem of work-directories, for your information: the python script is saved in a directory of `/var/www/html`.

If this could be an issue with the `Image.save()` method of PIL, note that I have tried doing a similar thing with `open(filename, 'w')`. Same error.

I have looked for similar questions everywhere, but none seems to fit my issue. Am I overseeing something? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the user does not have permissions on that directory/file.

When using Python, you usually work on a [Virtual Env](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/).

You can check which user the virtualenv is using with

```
import os

print "Env thinks the user is [%s]" % (os.getlogin())
```

And check the actual user executing the task with

```
import getpass

print "Effective user is [%s]" % (getpass.getuser())
```

If they don't match maybe that can give you a starting point.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I indeed noticed that if I execute the code by myself, it works fine. However, when I use your code, it give me a `OSError: [Errno 6] No such device or address`. Why?

Comment: Is the Python virtualenv active when you make that call?

Comment: I don't have a python virtualenv. I execute the file throught php. Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, set up the virtualenv and then execute your python script through it. (See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718467/using-php-to-call-virtualenv-ed-python-script ) It is not hard! :)

Comment: The script works when I just save the file under "/tmp". I think I will keep it like that, thanks anyways for your answer, it helped a lot! :)

Comment: I'm glad it did! :)